# Location Based Product Recommendation Service Using Content Based Recommendations with ASP.Net & C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, data-mining, recommendation-engine

I am in a bit of a crisis here. I would really appreciate your help on the matter.

My Final Year Project is a **"Location Based Product Recommendation Service"**. Now, due to some communication gap, we got stuck with an extremely difficult algorithm. Here is how it went:

We had done some research about recommendation systems prior to the project defense. We knew there were two approaches, **"Collaborative Filtering"** and **"Content Based Recommendation"**. We had planned on using whichever technique gave us the best results. So, in essence, we were more focused on the end product than the actual process. The HOD asked us what algorithms OUR product would use? But, my group members thought that he meant what are the algorithms that are used for "Content Based Recommendations". They answered with "Rule Mining, Classification and Clustering". He was astonished that we planned on using all these algorithms for our project. He told us that he would accept our project proposal if we use his algorithm in our project. He gave us his research paper, without any other resources such as data, simulations, samples, etc. The algorithm is named **"Context Based Positive and Negative Spatio-Temporal Association Rule Mining"** In the paper, this algorithm was used to recommend sites for hydrocarbon taps and mining with extremely accurate results. Now here are a few issues I face:

- I am not sure how or **IF** this algorithm fits in our project scenario
- I cannot find spatio-temporal data, MarketBaskets, documentation or indeed any helpful resource
- I tried asking the HOD for the data he used for the paper, as a reference. He was unable to provide the data to me
- I tried coding the algorithm myself, in an incremental fashion, but found I was completely out of my depth. I divided the algo in 3 phases. Positive Spatio-Temporal Association Rule Mining, Negative Spatio-Temporal Association Rule Mining and Context Based Adjustments. Alas! The code I write is not mature enough. I couldn't even generate frequent itemsets properly. I understand the theory quite well, but I am not able to translate it into efficient code.
- When the algorithm has been coded, I need to develop a web service. We also need a client website to access the web service. But with the code not even 10% done, I really am panicking. The project submission is in a fortnight.
- Our supervisor is an expert in Artificial Intelligence, but he cannot guide us in the algorithm development. He dictates the importance of reuse and utilizing open-source resources. But, I am unable to find anything of actual use.
- My group members are waiting on me to deliver the algorithm, so they can deploy it as a web service. There are other adjustments than need to be done, but with the algorithm not available, there is nothing we can do.
- I have found a data set of Market Baskets. It's a simple excel file, with about 9000 transactions. There is not spatial or temporal data in it and I fear adding artificial data would compromise the integrity of the data.

I would appreciate if somebody could guide me. I guess the best approach would be to use an open-source API to partially implement the algorithm and then build the service and client application. We need to demonstrate something on 17th of June. I am really looking forward to your help, guidance and constructive criticism. Some solutions that I have considered are:

- Use "User Clustering" as a "Collaborate Filtering" technique. Then
  recommend the products from similar users via an alternative "Rule
  Mining" algorithm. I need all these algorithms to be openly available
  either as source code or an API, if I have any chance of making this
  project on time.
- Drop the algorithm altogether and make a project that actually works
  as we intended, using available resources. I am 60% certain that we
  would fail or marked extremely low.
- Pay a software house to develop the algorithm for us and then
  over-fit it into our project. I am not inclined to do this because it
  would be unethical to do this.

As you can clearly see, my situation is quite dire. I really do need extensive help and guidance if I am to complete this project properly, in time. The project needs to be completely deployed and operational. I really am in a loop here

Answer (score 0):

"Collaborative Filtering", "Content Based Recommendation", "Rule Mining, Classification and Clustering"

**None of these are algorithms**. They are tasks or subtasks, for each of which several algorithms exist.

I think you had a bad start already by not really knowing well enough what you proposed... but granted, the advice from your advisor was also not at all helpful.

Comment: Well, there exist several open-source libraries. I think even for C#, although most is Linux oriented. Choose wisely, not by sales pitches.